# Python multithreading error "group argument must be None for now"

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have created a class "MyThread" which inherits "Thread" class and one other class "Main" which is again defined in my project. When I try to instantiate the object of "MyThread" class, it gives the exception "group argument must be None for now". Below is the code:

```
    myThreadObject1 = myThread.MyThread("Thread 1",True)

    class MyThread (threading.Thread,main.Main):
def __init__(self,name,flag):
    try:
        #threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        super(MyThread,self).__init__(self) 
        self.threadName = name
        self.flag = flag
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to python folder and find "threading.py". After that commit assert line as shown below

```
#assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
```

Note: You must be admin.

Answer (score 0):

You've called the thread constructor incorrectly, it should be

```
super(MyThread, self).__init__()
```

The call to init already gets self sent to it, so when you provide it again it sets another argument in the Thread class constructor and things get confused.